# How to remove a url paramaters via get without lost the values send PHP, javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, get

I've the following template, that render a list o links, each link has a code, and name like `a <a name="codigo" class="integrantes" href="#000356">Name of someone<a>`

```xhtml
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion-integrantes">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#integrantes>">
            <?php echo $this->titulo; ?>
          </a>
        </h4>
  </div>

  <div id="integrantes" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">  
        <div class="table-responsive" >
          <table class="table table-hover" id="table-integrantes">
            <?php foreach($this->integrantes as $key => $value ): ?>
            <tr>
              <td>  <a  name="codigo" class="integrantes" code="<?php echo $key; ?> "> <?php echo $value ?> </a></td>  
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I wanna send a code vía get in the url, so I use the following function on javascript

```js
$(function(){
 $('.integrantes').bind( 'click',function(){
    var code = $(this).attr( 'code');
    window.location.href = "CVLACController.php?code=" + code; 
 });
});
```

When I press the link y send a code  I and get a url lik  `http://testdomain.com/CVLACController.php?code=0000292915`

It's fine, but Whe I generete a view with my controller and I use a [collapse boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) , that it use a `id-of-div`  to expand o collapse a div, the problem is that it find the 
`id-of-div` like a

http://tesdomain.com/CVLACController.php?code=0000292915#id-of-div

But this wrong, I hope something  like

http://testdomain.com/CVLACController.php#id-of-div

Now, I don't know how to remove the url parameters without lost the value of the variable dispatched. To apply the accrodion boostrap

how to send the parameters via post in this case, the right way  and work fine the [collapse-bostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse%5D)?

or

how to remove the parameters of the url without lost the values of the variables and work fine the [collapse-bostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)?

Comment: When you apply bootstrap, do you want to make previous code work? I mean, when you use collapse bootstrap, when clicking element it redirects to `.....?code=xxxx` do you still want it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden form and post your `code` and it won't seen in the url. Here is an example;

```
<form id="send_code" action="CVLACController.php" type="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="code" id="code" value=""/>
</form>
```

you can put any above form anywhere in your page, and in your js;

```
$(function(){
 $('.integrantes').bind( 'click',function(){
    var code = $(this).attr( 'code');
    $("#code").val(code);
    $("#send_code").submit(); 
 });
});
```

By doing this, you can post code value to `CVLACController.php` without any parameter in url. And do not forget to get `code` in `CVLACController.php`;

```
$code = $_POST["code"];
```

Comment: It's works(partial), but when I try to do some object instantece not works, because I get a mistake that say me  **Trying to get property of non-object**.

Comment: Could you please also state that instantiation on your question?